# How to force a browser to get new headers without declaring expires?

Tags: http, nginx, http-headers, content-security-policy

We have an established site that is now being effected by CSP rules. I’ve added all the scripts we need to the `Content-Security-Policy` header.

When visiting the site using private browsing or a device that hasn’t been to the site before, I get the new CSP header and everything works.

However, users that have been to the site before get the old headers, and they get CSP warning.

**NB** I cannot use `expire 0` or similar as the browsers *are not looking for the new headers*, so never know that the headers have expired.

I’m looking for a way to tell the browser “hey, you should checkout my cool new headers because they’re new”.

Comment: So there are currently clients out there which still have a fresh cache? Then there's no way to force anything on them from the server-side, since **they're not going to ask the server at all until their cache expires.** You could tell your users to manually refresh (hitting refresh twice in the browser usually does it, otherwise cleaning the cache), but there's probably nothing you can do to automate this except wait.

Comment: What’s odd is that I can’t replicate it with a hard refresh, or even clearing my own cache in Chrome. If I open an incognito window it works, but if I clear my cache and do a hard refresh, I still get the same problem. It’s like there’s some sort of secret headers cache that I can’t clear.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was being foiled by Local Storage that was overwriting the CSP header. Even clearing the cache doesn’t solve the problem as Local Storage remains.

Hope this helps somebody else!

Comment: How is localStorage overriding a response header?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev there was a custom script that we were unaware of getting in the way